# Get observeEvent to manipulate data object in workspace

Tags: r, shiny

I would like to filter some data in the R Workspace from within the App/ an actionButton.

I tried the following in the server part:

```
observeEvent(input$ClickMyButton, { dat <- dat[dat$Var2 < 100, ] })
```

dat is a dataframe in the Workspace, i.e. global Environment.

How can I achieve such an "action"?

Comment: I don't think we can: http://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/scoping.html

Comment: Have you tried the `<<-` operator mentioned in the link above?

Comment: You can use `<<-` (though it's generally discouraged). If you want to specifically modify a value stored in the global environment (workspace) then you can also use the `assign()` function and specify the global env